# Can NULL indicators be used in the WHERE clause for COBOL embedded SQL?

Tags: null, cobol, cics, embedded-sql

I am working on a CICS screen where the users can query, add, update or delete data in a table. In one of my tables, the unique key is made of 5 fields, 2 of which can be NULL. In my cursor I'm having to use an

```
AND   (COLUMN_1 = :V??-REC.COLUMN-1 OR COLUMN-1 IS NULL)
```

and then I am having to run an evaluation on the results and display the closest matching result.

How I am currently finding NULL entries:

```
EXEC SQL
    DECLARE V000001-CUR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DOCM_N,
           DOCM_TYPE_T,
           REJ_RESN_C
    FROM   V000001
    WHERE  DOCM_N      = :V000001-REC.DOCM-N
    AND    DOCM_TYPE_T = :V000001-REC.DOCM-TYPE-T
    AND   (REJ_RESN_C  = :V000001-REC.REJ-RESN-C OR
           REJ_RESN_C IS NULL)
END-EXEC
```

---

I have read online that null indicators can be used to insert NULL into the table when using update or insert.

For example:

```
EXEC SQL
    UPDATE V000001
    SET    DOCM_N      = :V000001-REC.DOCM-N,
           DOCM_TYPE_T = :V000001-REC.DOCM-TYPE-T,
           REJ_RESN_C  = :V000001-REC.REJ-RESN-C
                           :WS-REJ-RESN-C-IND
    WHERE  DOCM_N      = :WW-DOCM-N
    AND    DOCM_TYPE_T = :WW-DOCM-TYPE-T
END-EXEC
```

---

**My question. Can I use the null indicator in the WHERE clause?**

Such as:

```
EXEC SQL
    DECLARE V000001-CUR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DOCM_N,
           DOCM_TYPE_T,
           REJ_RESN_C
    FROM   V000001
    WHERE  DOCM_N      = :V000001-REC.DOCM-N
    AND    DOCM_TYPE_T = :V000001-REC.DOCM-TYPE-T
    AND    REJ_RESN_C  = :V000001-REC.REJ-RESN-C
                            :WS-REJ-RESN-C-IND
END-EXEC
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### !!! **For DB2 Version 8 and onwards** !!!

To use a `NULL` indicator in the `WHERE` clause for a `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` you need to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

Because `NULL` is an unknown it doesn't have a value, it can never equal anything - not even another `NULL`.

So, when you want to find an entry by matching on user input - after you have moved the user input to the required fields - you would normally use something like:

```
EXEC SQL
    SELECT COLUMN_1,
           COLUMN_2,
           COLUMN_3
    FROM   V000001
    WHERE  COLUMN_1 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-1
    AND    COLUMN_2 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-2
    AND    COLUMN_3 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-3
END-EXEC
```

Or the equivalent `UPDATE` or `DELETE` SQL depending on the required function.

If `COLUMN_1` has the potential to be `NULL` we would use a null indicator when fetching the data into a cursor and when trying to update/add a `NULL` to a table - but matching on a `NULL` in a `WHERE` clause isn't as simple.

Because `NULL` doesn't contain a value we CAN'T use the null indicator in the `WHERE` statement like so:

```
WHERE COLUMN_1 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-1 :COLUMN-1-IND
```

and once you starting using brackets and `OR xxxx IS NULL` (seen below) you need to start programming in all sorts of other checks so you don't retrieve, update or delete the wrong row

```
WHERE (COLUMN_1 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-1 OR COLUMN_1 IS NULL)
```

---

**The correct way to use a null indicator in the `WHERE` clause is like so:**

```
EXEC SQL
    SELECT COLUMN_1,
           COLUMN_2,
           COLUMN_3
    FROM   V000001
    WHERE  COLUMN_1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM
                      :V000001-REC.COLUMN-1
                         :COLUMN-1-IND
    AND    COLUMN_2 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-2
    AND    COLUMN_3 = :V000001-REC.COLUMN-3
END-EXEC
```

Since a working `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` can be transferred to other statements, this also works for finding an exact match when doing an `UPDATE` or a `DELETE`

---

More reading: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/6842.nulls